# Gtk+ в Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, gtk+

В общем, ситуация такая.

Я хочу разрабатывать **GUI** на **C** в **Windows 10**. Все рекомендуют использовать для этой цели **GTK+**.

Да, я знаю о существовании **Qt** и **C++**, какое-то время я работал с **C++**, вполне неплохо его знаю, в том числе и **C++11/14**, в связи с чем умышленно и обоснованно не хотел бы использовать этот язык в моей работе. Мне уже хватило с ним проблем и сложностей. С языком **C** проблем практически нет. Он работает, как автомат Калашникова.

Вопрос не во вкусах, а в долгосрочном планировании.

Мне очень нравится **GTK+** в плане **API**. Проблема в том, что установленный по официальному мануалу **GTK+** под **Windows** работает криво.

Во-первых, **Glade** стабильно падает. Любая версия, которую мне удалось найти, даже та, которая ставится через **MSYS2**.

Во-вторых, даже простое окно с десятком виджетов, очень тормозит, а при изменении его размера в консоли постоянно появляются всякие фэйлы, предупреждения и, в конце-концов, вываливается **segmentation fault**.

1) Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Таких проблем ведь быть не должно? Или у всех так? Мне просто не верится, что релиз **GTK+** под **Windows** выпущен с такими серьезными проблемами.

2) Может быть есть альтернативы для **GTK+**? Не хотелось бы писать **GUI** на **Win API**.

3) На чем вообще сейчас принято писать **GUI**? Желательно, конечно, что-то, что имеет возможность легко связываться с библиотеками **DLL**, написанными на **C**.

Comment: Альтернативы WinAPI: [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) (на нём написаны такие IDE как CodeBlocks и CodeLite), C# WinForms/WPF,  Delphi VCL.

Comment: Меня интересуют библиотеки под C, про перечисленное я знаю, спасибо.

Comment: Сам не пробавал, но может как вариант http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/

Comment: Надо попробовать, интересная штука. А насчет GTK+, у вас были с ней проблемы?

Comment: Да проблемы были. Я даже разбираться не стал. Тупо плюнул на это дело.

Comment: Я так не могу, я должен понять <красные глаза>

Comment: С GTK+  проблем не было все отлично работает .